# Does the Google Cloud Build API Support API Keys authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Build's REST API: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/list

I'm wondering if it's possible to authenticate with this API by using an API Key, I tried passing the key parameter:

```
GET https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project>/builds?key=<key>
```

But this results in a 401 error message. Is there an extra step required? How do you authenticate with this API?

For context, I'm trying to use this API from a Cloud Function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible with using only  [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) "A limited number of GCP services allow access using only an API key:". Please use a service account instead.

Comment: I'm wondering, how do you use the REST API with service accounts then? The service account attached to the cloud function should have the necessary privileges, and sending a request to the REST API returns a 401 as well.

Comment: You will need the access token from the OAuth 2.0 auth server and the service account will request for the access token.

GET https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECTID]/triggers HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: @CarlosMartinez - I have written a bunch of articles on using service accounts including calling REST APIs. https://www.jhanley.com

Comment: They really made it complicated with this API, it's not in the SDKs either as far as I can tell